# URL bar shows I'm viewing a different page (file) but the browser doesn't actually display said page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm just starting out on a website using Reactstrap. I've got my homepage made, so i put a link in the nav bar to go to a new page (JS file in the same directory). When I click the link, the url bar shows that I'm at that file, the page refreshes, but no matter what it still shows the original page I started on, even if I make completely blank page with nothing on it for it to go to.
 `<NavItem>
<NavLink href="ContactUs.js">Contact Us</NavLink>
</NavItem>`
 I can provide more code if needed, but I just don't get why my code would have anything to do with it at this point, when I can implement the exact same thing except a link to a different website and have it work fine

Comment: this seems like a server redirecting back to your index html which is a valid approach for a lot of websites please contact your server provider to chagne this behaviour

Comment: nothing is being hosted. this is all "localhost"

Comment: so its still hosted but local ("local-host" :3) which webserver are you using ?